# Relevance of the ZeroSum game to Heuristic search?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, heuristics

A question was posed to me as to the relevance of the ZeroSum game to Heuristic search algorithms.

I know that the zero sun game is a theory in which one persons gain is exactly balanced to another persons loss but I am unsure as to how this applies to Heuristics.

I think it may have something to do with how parts of the problem space are removed and as a result, the problem space is optimised?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by _the_ ZeroSum game? There are some games that can are zero sum, but this is a class of games, not a single one. Could you clarify what sort of relation are you looking for? Are you looking how to apply heuristics in strategies for zero-sum games?

Comment: Any application of such zero sum game used to implement a heuristic, that you could think of?